# Placing a gravity form on top of an image, with text next to it

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, gravity

I am using wordpress, 
    I'm inputting the HTML with a WYSIWYG 
    I'm using the Custom CSS plug in, to avoid going into the themes style sheet. 
    I'm using Gravity Forms as the form plug in.

I don't know where I'm going wrong if truth be told, I am either getting the form with a background image, or a background image with no form.

I'd ideally like to have a large image, a small box on top of the image to the left containing the form with a dark background, and some text to the right.

Comment: BASIC is another language so probably shouldn't have added that tag.

Comment: Can you include some code? Any html, css, php and/ or javascript.

Comment: I removed the BASIC tag pending peer review.  On average I remove one BASIC tag a day.  Amazing how many people have no idea what "basic" means.

Comment: Sorry about this, noted for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem: replace Form shortcode by the form shortcode, the url in css with the path of the image you want to use and the Column2, Some text.. with the text you want to add. hope it helps.

```
/*=================place this in the css stylesheet========*/
    .row .column {
        box-sizing: border-box;}
    .row{
background-image: url(http://gowash.ancorathemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/slide1.jpg);
background-size: cover;
      }

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 300px; 
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both; 
    }



/*=place this in the page where you want to add the form=*/  

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <h2>Form shortcode</h2>

      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!